# No project under project settings in pyCharm. Project not recognized

Tags: python, pycharm, ide, python-venv

I have accidentally deleted venv and .idea folders from my project in pyCharm. I have recreated venv folder using python3 -m venv venv but I can't seem to be able to get the project recognize it.

I can't configure project settings in pyCharm settings, since project menu entry is missing there.

Is there a way to get my project recognized again without creating a new one and moving scripts there?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can drag and drop the project's folder onto PyCharm's starting window (the one where projects are listed). That will open it as a project and create a new `.idea` folder. PyCharm should detect the existing venv and suggest it as the project's interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to fix it.
I have created new empty project, taken .idea and venv folders from there and copied it to old folder and it somehow works. Not sure that I won't find bugs there, but for now looks good.

Comment: was excellent for me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could open your project and right-click project name find [Local History -> Show History].
Try to reset .idea

Comment: How can history help me to reset .idea? I would like to keep my existing code and there have been a bunch of commits after that